# Trying to find which cases relate to at least two of the names on a list SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to find which cases relate to at least two of the names on my list. All of the data is found in the same table. I would like my query to produce the list of the cases that have more than 2 of the same names related to them as well as which names they are related to. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT related_persons.name
FROM related_persons
WHERE related_persons.case_number =
    (SELECT related_persons.case_number
     FROM related_persons
     WHERE related_persons.name LIKE 'A%'
    OR NAME LIKE 'B%'
    OR NAME LIKE 'C%'
    OR NAME LIKE 'D%'
    OR NAME LIKE 'E%'
    OR NAME LIKE 'F%');
```

I am getting an error that says `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.

I have also tried the following:

```
SELECT
    related_persons.case_number
FROM
    related_persons
GROUP by related_persons.case_number
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN NAME LIKE 'A%' OR NAME LIKE 'B%' OR NAME LIKE 'C%' OR NAME LIKE 'D%  OR NAME LIKE 'E%'  OR NAME LIKE 'F%' THEN 1 else 0 END) >= 2;
```

But this gives me case number that just have 1 match.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try IN subquery instead of = subquery.

Comment: Post a data sample and expected output.

Comment: name >= 'A' AND name < 'G'

Comment: You ask for "more than 2" but your attempt has `SUM(...) >= 2`. Which is it? More than 2, or at least 2?

Comment: By "same names" do you mean 1) names are the same, or 2) names both start with the same letter, or 3) names both start with a letter in the range A-F, or 4) something else? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Bohemian apologies for the confusion. What I mean to say is if two of the names on my list are related to the same case number. So at least 2 different names belonging to the 1 case number.

Comment: @vidada OK, the names must be different eg `BOB` and `BRAD`, but at least one of them must start with `A-F`, both must start with `A-F`, both must start with `A-F` but a different `A-F`, both must start with the same `A-F` but be different or `A-F` doesn't matter? Please provide sample data!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE:

```
WITH Names AS (
    SELECT LEFT(name, 1) AS iniLetter, COUNT(*) qty
    FROM related_persons
    GROUP BY LEFT(name, 1)
    HAVING LEFT(name, 1) IN ('B','C','D','E','F')
)
SELECT related_persons.case_number
FROM related_persons 
JOIN Names on iniLetter = LEFT(name,1)
```

Comment: `SUM(*)` is invalid. Did you mean `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: Yes thank you @Bohemian

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want, so I'm guessing. However, I'm reasonably sure you can solve it by joining the table to itself finding a different name in the join.

This find cases that have two names with different starting letters, but both start with A-F:

```
select distinct t1.case_number
from related_persons t1
join related_persons t2 on t2.case_number = t1.case_number
  and left(t2.name, 1) between 'A' and 'F'
  and left(t2.name, 1) != left(t1.name, 1)
where left(t1.name, 1) between 'A' and 'F'
```

If the A-F thing is not needed and you just want to find two different names:

```
select t1.case_number
from related_persons t1
join related_persons t2 on t2.case_number = t1.case_number
  and t2.name > t1.name
```